# Many to many relation with fk in the pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

i have the following structure:

## Database

**ingredients**
id,
name

**products**
id,
name

**ingredient_product**
ingredient_id,
product_id,
ingredient_type_id

**ingredient_types**
id,
name

## Models

**Product** Model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function ingredients() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredient::class)
            ->withPivot('ingredient_type_id');
    }
}
```

**Ingredient** Model

```
class Ingredient extends Model
{
    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
            ->withPivot('ingredient_type_id');
    }
}
```

My **SearchController**

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function search(InitialSearchRequest $request)
    {
        $productsResults = Product::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request['initial-search'] . '%')
            ->with('ingredients', 'brand')
            ->get();

        return view('search.index')
            ->with(compact('productsResults'))
            ->with('initial-search', $request['initial-search']);

    }
}
```

And finally my **View**

```
<div class="card-group">
    @foreach($productsResults as $product)
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card"><img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Imagem do produto" style="width: 100%; height:100px; background-color: #696969;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->name }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        Important Ingredients: <br>
                        @foreach($product->ingredients as $ingredient)
                            **{{ I need here the ingredient type }}** - {{ $ingredient->name }}
                        @endforeach
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

So i need to show in the view my products, with the ingredients and the type of each ingredient.

This approach isn´t working......

I need help to finish this task.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pivot model:

```php
class IngredientProductPivot extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot
{
    public function ingredientType() {
        return $this->belongsTo(IngredientType::class);
    }
}

class Product extends Model
{
    public function ingredients() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredient::class)
            ->withPivot('ingredient_type_id')
            ->using(IngredientProductPivot::class);
    }
}
```

Then access it like this:

```
{{ $ingredient->pivot->ingredientType->name }}
```

As far as I know, there is no way to eager load the `type` relation.